# flask error when urequests.post on micropython esp8266

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I just make api with flask and have error urequests.post on micropython esp8266 this is my code

flask.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
import os, sys

cert = os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'cert.pem')
key = os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'key.pem')

app = Flask(__name__)

context = (cert, key)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return {'data': 'demo'}

@app.route('/demo', methods = ['POST'])
def demo_post():
    content = request.get_json()
    print(content)
    return content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000', debug = True, ssl_context = context)
    #app.run(port='5000', debug = True)
```

normal_requests(work).py

```
import requests
requests.get('https://example.com/').json()
>>> {'data': 'demo'}
requests.post('https://example.com/demo', json={"a":5,"b":4}).json()
>>> {"a":5,"b":4}
```

micropython_urequests(work).py

```
import urequests
urequests.get('https://example.com/').json()
>>> {'data': 'demo'}
```

---

**error this line**

```
urequests.post('https://example.com/demo', json={"a":5,"b":4}).json()
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/programing/myenv/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/pi/programing/myenv/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/pi/programing/myenv/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/pi/programing/myenv/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/pi/programing/myenv/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/pi/programing/myenv/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/pi/programing/myenv/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/home/pi/programing/myenv/flask/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2098, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [check examples for post in urequests](https://makeblock-micropython-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_library/Third-party-libraries/urequests.html)

use `ujson.dumps` return to `dict` represented as a JSON string.

```
import urequests
import ujson

post_data = ujson.dumps({"a":5,"b":4})

res = urequests.post('https://example.com/demo', headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}, data = post_data).json()
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhh you made my day, it works thank you ;)